# Three numbers, three words

Tags: word, password

Given only these 3 numbers below, find the 3 words related to:

- An animal
- A car brand
- A drink

Numbers:

- 456448711
- 875654332
- 7456987877

Hint:

> It's simple enough to be solved in less than a minute

Comment: Are we supposed to match each word to a specific number? Or find an overarching theme?

Comment: @Bewilderer You can find a word with each number

Comment: Is [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/T9_(predictive_text)) a correct path?

Comment: @athin no, you can actually solve this in less than a minute, it's not something hard ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If you google the numbers, the top result you get for
>  1) https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/coffee-cup-tasty-drink-456448711 (cup of coffee)
>
>  2) Now this search returns (on the image tab) an outfit with a horse. So this is what I'm gonna go for.
>
>  3) https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiK7fzS2q7iAhVdShUIHRioDZsQFjAFegQIBBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Farchiwum.allegro.pl%2Foferta%2Fbugatti-modna-kurtka-29-xl-i7456987877.html&usg=AOvVaw2eAH0imeTCo5Q5YYWP-XGY (this links to some jackets but the model name is BUGATTI which is a make of a car)

Comment: Probably not incorrect :)